# 'ngModel' using with 'name' attribute giving error type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<input type="radio" [value]="q.option1" [name]="i" [(ngModel)]="q.givenAnswer"/>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information. Just posting the throwen error and the one line of code wont do it. What is your `i`? How does your object `q` looks like? Do you set the `i` anywhere? Please provide some more information so that the community can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute as described in the error needs a string. I'm guessing that `i` is an index? If so when you use square brackets it uses the value as is. Try changing it to something like this:

`name="{{ i }}"`

Or convert it to a string another way before using it.

Comment: or `[name]="''+i"` (personally I don't like use interpolation to forze an attribute to String)